# use node.js send request for baidu map API get wrong response?

Tags: node.js, httprequest, baidu

Im trying to use node.js to send http requst and call baidu map API.
my code in blow:

If you past the url and use browser directly, it will give right response in right format.

But when I use node to send request, I get problem.

```
var request = require('request');
  request(
    { method: 'GET',
      uri: 'http://api.map.baidu.com/place/v2/suggestion?query=beijing&region=131&output=json&ak=****hLQKu9ap9fPq5N1ExF1Kk7xe5Eah'
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {

      res.json({
        res:response
      })
    }
  )
```

Meanwhile, if I change the url contains some Chinese like:

```
http://api.map.baidu.com/place/v2/suggestion?query=北京理工大学&region=北京&output=json&ak=****hLQKu9ap9fPq5N1ExF1Kk7xe5Eah
```

In node.js it will give status code 400 and totally wrong response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must encode your uri with [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

```
uri: encodeURI('http://api.map.baidu.com/place/v2/suggestion?query=北京理工大学&region=北京&output=json&ak=3104hLQKu9ap9fPq5N1ExF1Kk7xe5Eah')
```